# (Javascript) How to loop through all JSON objects but only get a specific value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

JSON:

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "One",
  "value": "Hello 1",
  "enabled": true,
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Two",
  "value": "Hello 2",
  "enabled": true,
 },
 {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Three",
  "value": "Hello 3",
  "enabled": true,
 }
]
```

I want to loop through all objects, but only get "name" and "value". How would I do that?

Comment: In addition to adding your attempt, can you also please add an example of your expected output? Not sure if you're after an array of objects or just strings

Comment: If you just want to log: `array.forEach(({ name, value }) => console.log(name, value))`. IF you want to get another array of obejcts with subset of each object: `const output = array.map(({ name, value }) => ({ name, value }))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope be useful ;)
good luck

```js
const jsn = [
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "One",
  "value": "Hello 1",
  "enabled": true,
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Two",
  "value": "Hello 2",
  "enabled": true,
 },
 {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Three",
  "value": "Hello 3",
  "enabled": true,
 }
];

const newJsn = [];

jsn.forEach(item => {
  newJsn.push({name: item.name, value: item.value}) 
});

console.log(newJsn)
```